# Detect session expired or session timeout using spring3

Tags: spring, session, request

How to Detect session expired or session timeout using spring3.

Comment: What do you mean "detect"? Where do you want to detect it?

Comment: @cdeszaq: I would assume he means trigger some function

Comment: Please add some detail. Are your users authenticating via spring security? Do you want to handle the expired sessions dynamically with javascript, or statically via re-direction to some other page? What is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

The key is this:

```
<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.htm" />
</beans:bean>
```

expiredUrl points to the page to display when a session has expired. Read the full solution in the spec :

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#concurrent-sessions